# SQL: how to check if a date in the list has changed in iteration asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

The scenario that I have so far is, I am fetching the logs from a device and storing it in the db sequentially with `Checktype` as `I` and `O` saying that his first entry was check-in and then check-out sequentially. This worked fine until I came up to an issue like;

Lets assume an emp has 3 logs in the device, 1 log for the date 15-feb-2018 and 2 logs on the date 16-feb-2018, what the query will do is it will insert the records as;

15-feb-2018 `I`

16-feb-2018 `O`

16-feb-2018 `I`

which is definitely wrong. it should be like

15-feb-2018 `I`

16-feb-2018 `I`

16-feb-2018 `O`

Current code snippet:

```
public static bool inn = true;
public ActionResult GetLogs()
{                
    if (isDevice2Connected)
    {          
//.. some code that fetches the logs
        if (lstMachineInfo != null && lstMachineInfo.Count > 0)
        {
            var lastRecord = db.AttLogs.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime).FirstOrDefault();

            List<Employee> empList = db.Emps.ToList();
            var checkSingle = db.Perms.Where(x => x.Name == "Single" && x.IsPermitted == true).ToList();

            if (lastRecord != null)
            {
                lstMachineInfo = lstMachineInfo.Where(x => x.DateTime > lastRecord.DateTime).ToList();
            }

            foreach(var emp in empList)
            {
//this is where it should have some `Date` check
                var empLogs = lstMachineInfo.Where(x => x.RegisterationId == int.Parse(emp.EnrollNumber)).ToList();

                foreach (var p in empLogs)
                {
                    if (checkSingle.Count > 0)
                    {
                        if (inn)
                        {
                            inn = false;
                            p.CheckType = "I";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            inn = true;
                            p.CheckType = "O";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        p.CheckType = "SINGLE DEVICE DEACTIVATED IN PERMISSIONS CHECK";
                    }
                    db.AttLogs.Add(p);
                }
            }
            db.SaveChanges();                  
        }
    }
    return View("GetAllUserInfo");
}
```

UPDATE:
trying to get the date from the empsLogs list so I can check if it has changed?

```
                    foreach (var p in empLogs)
                    {

                        if (checkSingle.Count > 0)
                        {
                            if (empLogs.Where(x => x.Date > NEXTDATEINLIST? ))
                                inn = true;
```

Comment: Okay, your situation is more or less clear. What is your question?

Comment: how do I get the Nextdate from the `empLogs` so i can check it has changed the boolean value of `inn` should be set to true again.?

Comment: The code is fine. Just remove the question mark after NEXTDATEINLIST, make it into a proper variable and do not forget to update it in the loop.

Comment: You could alter the schema of the data. GROUP BY date, include the ROWCOUNT, put I on rowcount=1 and O on rowcount=2 and insert (you no longer need to handle the flag, I/O are already available and correct)

Comment: @Alex pardon me but i could not follow. perhaps an example would be helpful! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, all you need is to use `p.Date` instead of the variable and also a way to increment it like:

```
  foreach(var emp in empList)
  {
     var empLogs = lstMachineInfo.Where(x => x.RegisterationId == int.Parse(emp.EnrollNumber)).ToList();
     var prevDate = (from obj in empLogs select obj.Date).FirstOrDefault();

       foreach (var p in empLogs)
        {                   
          if (checkSingle.Count > 0)
          {
             if (prevDate < p.Date) {
                 inn = true;
                  prevDate = p.Date;
          }
          if (inn)
          {
            inn = false;
            p.CheckType = "I";
          }
          else
          {
           inn = true;
           p.CheckType = "O";
          }
   }
          else
          {
           p.CheckType = "SINGLE DEVICE DEACTIVATED IN PERMISSIONS CHECK";
          }
          db.AttendanceLogs.Add(p);
  }
}
          db.SaveChanges();
```